# Passing multiple arguments in qt slot

Tags: qt4, qwidget

Can we pass two arguments in a qt slot using *QSignalMapper* ? I have to pass an int and a *QWidget* to a slot...I just learnt about passing a single argument and i am stuck in case of two arguments.